# How the Throughput,Kb/sec and average bytes are measured in Summary Report?

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone please explain me how the throughput,Kb/sec and average bytes are measured in the Summary Report?

I got following Summary Report for login action.

```
Label : Login Action(sampler)
Sample# : 1
average: 104    
min : 104
max : 104
stddev : 0
error% : 0
Throughput : 9.615384615
Kb/Sec : 91.74053486
Average Bytes : 9770
```

Could you please give me the detail explanation? I cant clear when gone through google.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

**Througput in KB/s = (Transaction Throughput* Average Bytes) / 1024**

For example:

```
91.74053486  = (9.615384615 X 9770) / 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

These values are detailed [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report). They're fairly self explanatory.

Comment: Sorry. I can't clear what it means request per second and KB/sec. Is it for all requests or a single request. Is Avg. bytes are calculated for response? Can u please clarify this..